# Need help on Chain Rule for multivariate function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am given the function $S(t) = v\begin{pmatrix}t, 1-t, \frac{1}{1-t}\end{pmatrix}$. I need to find $S'(t)$ in terms of $t,\,v'_1,\,v'_2\,v'_3$. How do I do so?

I am thinking of the following:

$$
\begin{align*}
S'(t) &= v'_1 +v'_2\dot{} -1 + v'_3\dot{}\frac{1}{(1-t)^2}\\&=v'_1-v'_2+\frac{v'_3}{(1-t)^2}
\end{align*}
$$

Any ideas if this sounds correct?

Comment: Is $v$ a function with three variables such that $\operatorname{im}(v)\subseteq \Bbb R^3$?

Comment: Oh no, the question did not state...but since this is differentiation in real space, yes, $v$ is a function with 3 variables but they can be expressed in terms of 1 real variable $t$. of course, in this case $t \neq 1$

Comment: ah...i saw the error!

Comment: hey, not sure if you know this, but if i post my own ans to my own qn, i can only accept them in 48 hours...i will follow up in due time.

Comment: Good job. ${}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the community, it has been verified as correct.